# How do you execute pyqt .ui code in python?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am making a GUI for a script I am making, after researching I found *pyqt* would be helpful. I have now made a GUI with no working buttons as of yet in *pyqt* but wanted to look at the code.

I opened cmd.exe and typed in:

```
pyuic4 project.ui -o python.py
```

It created me a *python.py* script which showed me all the script I needed, however when I run it via IDLE or command prompt it shows it as running but no GUI opens up. Am I doing something wrong?

Also on a side note, is *pyqt* suitable to use to create a simple GUI for windows, or is it for mobile development?

Here is a snippet of code that i want to compile and run

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_FileHash(object):
    def setupUi(self, FileHash):
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [this tutorial](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html) on how to use the generated code by the pyuic4 command;

Basically, you need to do this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QDialog
from ui_project import Ui_Name  # here you need to correct the names

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QDialog()
ui = Ui_Name()
ui.setupUi(window)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Pyqt is completely suitable to create GUIs on Windows.

Comment: my file is currently project.ui, and i would like it to become project.py where you said i should correct names however I dont have any ui_project or ui_name. I tried to put 'import project.ui' but that did not work.

Comment: @DrKhan The command you executed generated a .py file, you need to put its name instead of "ui_project"

Comment: I must be getting my file names mixed up, i have added a code snippet, i hope this shows what i am trying to do.

Comment: I have got it working now, i typed in:
pyuic4 -x project.ui -o python.py

This gave me a .pyc file which opens fully and i can look at the code by typing the first command in my origonal code.

Answer (score 1):

As a notable addition, pyuic4 accepts a "-p" or "--preview" parameter which will preview the UI file by running it out of the box:

```
pyuic4 -p project.ui
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the pyuic4 options, -x option is the one you are missing. It adds the required code for executing the UI to your python code. You only need to add -x:

pyuic4 project.ui -x -o python.py

Comment: I used this and I get the hello.py. When I'm trying to execute this like `python hello.py` I see nothing. The widget is show and closes very quick.